# Showing an image with cURL

Tags: php, image, curl

Is it possible to show an image with cURL? I'd like to show an image without watermarks, so I need to pass it through the user agent. I have tried, but it's showing some encoded text.

```
function gets($url){
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
$img = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Bear_Alaska_%283%29.jpg/220px-Bear_Alaska_%283%29.jpg';
gets($img)
```

Answer (score 0):

As your curl return only image content, you have to change your header value. Try following code:

```
<?php
function gets($url){
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    $filename = basename($url);
    $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

    switch( $file_extension ) {
        case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
        case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
        case "jpeg":
        case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
        default:
    }

    header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
    echo $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
$img = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Bear_Alaska_%283%29.jpg/220px-Bear_Alaska_%283%29.jpg';
gets($img);
```

Answer (score -1):

You must set the header as the picture like following:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

If you can apply correct picture type out of followings:

- image/jpeg
- image/png
- image/gif

So simply your code can be updated like following:

```
function gets($url){
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
$img = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Bear_Alaska_%283%29.jpg/220px-Bear_Alaska_%283%29.jpg';
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo gets($img);
```

Comment: This work perfectly with those image, i have result just dot when i load the page. I have the url from exact data should i trim the url first or anything ?

Comment: @RafiHalilintar You will have to figure out CURL will fetch correct image what you wanna get. btw, can u accept my answer if it works?